# Common Lisp: Too few arguments given to function but cant find problem

Tags: function, arguments, lisp, common-lisp

im trying to create a simple c lisp program that finds and replaces symbols in a string of symbols. I am getting an error saying that I am giving too few arguments to the function.

```
(defun findandreplace (x y z)
  (if (eq 'x (first '(z))) 'y (first '(z))) 
  (findandreplace (rest '(z))))

(print (findandreplace 'x 'y '(x y x y z z x z)))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your code.

1. You use constant literals. Eg. `'(z)` literally evaluates to `(z)` and the symbol remains that and has *nothing to do with the binding `z`*. Makeing a list in CL with contents from a variable is done with the primitive `cons` and you have `list` that surely uses `cons` to create a proper list of all arguments. eg. `(list z)`. I cannot make sense of the logic if the intent was to use literals. Eg. `(first '(z))` can be simplified to just `'z`
2. The first `if` is dead code. Yes. the code evaluates to either `y` or `z`, but that value is discarded since `(findandreplace (rest '(z)))` is always evaluated right after. You probably should make sure every outcome is in tail position. eg. body is one big `cond` expression.
3. The recursive call `(findandreplace (rest '(z)))` only supplies one argument while the `defun` has 3 mandatory. This is the source of your error.
4. Since the variable names are vague it's not easy to guess what is the `olditem`, `newitem` and data to search. It would proably be better to mimick [substitute's argument naming](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sbs_s.htm)